# Javascript: Simple animation doesnt stop when setting flag to false

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to trigger animations on "mousedown" and immediately stop it once the mouse is released.

On "mousedown" I set a flag to true which sets the condition for the animation of the corresponding button clicked. The problem is on "mouseup" I set the flag to false but the animation doesnt stop. I dont get any errors in my console so it seems to be a logical based mistake.

What is my mistake here and how can I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/b4kn4w3g/2/

The essential code:

```
   function eventBundle(e) {
     if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
       if (e.target == parent.children[0]) {
         isDown = true;
         amount = "reduce";
       } else if (e.target == parent.children[1]) {
         isDown = true;
         amount = "increase";
       }
     }
     e.stopPropagation();
   }
   window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    isDown = false;
    amount = "neutral";
    });
   function holdStuff() {
     if (isDown == true && amount == "increase") {
       maxValue += 100;
     } else if (isDown == true && amount == "reduce") {
       maxValue -= 100;
     }
     requestAnimationFrame(holdStuff)
   }
```

Comment: whats your variable scope for isDown?

Comment: @AdamKonieska you can see it in my Jsfiddle. It has global scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `maxValue = minValue` to your `mouseup` event listener.  The issue is that your update function incrementally (by a value of 5) increases or decreases with `minValue += 5;` and `minValue -= 5;`.  When you increase or decrease the max by 100, it has to eventually get there by increments of 5.  Setting the maxValue to the current minValue stops the change at the current state.

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    maxValue = minValue;
    isDown = false;
    amount = "neutral";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nexrytes/

Comment: How did you figure that out? I really need some better strategy on finding logical problems in my code

Comment: It works, though an alternative better coding style is always welcome. I just heared that flags are a dumb idea : (

Comment: If I'm honest, I found it by experimenting.  I tried changing the `+= 100` to a 1 just to see what it would do.  I then figured that it was using the maxValue somehow to defer incrementing the angle over time.  After that I just did a search for all `maxValue` references in the code to see where it was being used or changed.  It was pretty easy after that simply because those two lines were the only places it was referenced in the update function.

Answer (score 1):

The animation doesn't stop on `mouseup` because the `update` function is still running periodically. You could do what Joseph said, or maybe cancel the updating when you don't need it. The `requestAnimationFrame` returns an ID which you can save, like this:

```
requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
```

and then you can cancel it like this:

```
cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
```